# How to downgrade PHP 5.4 to 5.3? Centos 6

Tags: centos, php

So I need to downgrade to 5.3 because of my script uses session_register, and it has been removed in php 5.4.

People have linked me to code that I should add to the script where the issue occurs, but they are all ioncubed files, so I can't really edit them.

Here are the errors I get since I switched to php 5.4.  http://travisingram.net/linkblaster/

That URL is apart of the script.

I have been googling fo quite some time and nothing has been helping really, they all provide some information on it, but then just stop somewhere...

Comment: Why don't you update your scripts?

Comment: Downgrading PHP isn't going to help, since some of your software's files are missing!

Comment: @Alex I don't understand PHP that well to just "change it".

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have One domain where I directly copied the files over, another domain where I had used the installer to let it run. I can assure you my files are not missing.

Comment: The error messages tell you they're missing. You'd better check again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I seriously know what I am doing, I ain't stupid to not see files. Again, I said its the PHP version.....

Comment: It certainly _looks_ like you don't know what you're doing. Read the error messages _carefully_ this time.